# How to read all data from Python socket.recv()?

Tags: python, sockets, recv

I'm trying to send mails through **smtp** protocol in a very simple, basic code.

```
import socket

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

port = 2525

clientSocket.connect(('localhost', port))
clientSocket.settimeout(5)

helo = 'HELO Me'
clientSocket.send(bytes(helo, 'utf-8'))

response = clientSocket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
print(f'Response: {response}')

# this response gets printed to the console

print('Succesfully connected via smtp')

mailFrom = 'MAIL FROM: myemail@gmail.com'
clientSocket.send(bytes(mailFrom, 'utf-8'))

response = clientSocket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
print(f'Response: {response}')

# here my program is blocked, and eventually gets a timeout
```

The problem is when I recieve the response, my, program stops running at the second response. I reckon my recv() function call is wrong, since if I change the first recv() **buffersize** to let's say 20, it works fine, so I guess there's still some data left in the socket. But how do I read it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is really a lot of problems in your program. The SMTP protocol is line oriented. You have to read incoming data into a buffer until you get CR LF chars which terminate each line. To comply with the protocol, you must terminate with CR LF each line you send. Most servers can handle unix lines terminated by LF only, but even this is missing. Use `socket.sendall`. Check the responses. If the server checks the hostname in "HELO me", it will not let you send anything.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't hang on the first command. As mentioned, you need to terminate all of your commands with `\r\n` and you have to follow the incoming protocols rules. For instance, HELO should receive lines until a response without a dash "-" is received. These protocols are kinda complicated, hence the modules that implement them for you!

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321

Comment: that \r\n was the problem....